# Emulating Hadoop Cluster On Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

This may be a silly question. I confess I am totally new to hadoop, so please bear with me.

But,

Is it possible to emulate master nodes for NameNode & JobTracker and multiple slave nodes for DataNode & TaskTracker on a single ubuntu installation without having to have multiple laptops/computers?

Is there anyway I can emulate multiple nodes for a fully distributed hadoop operation on a single ubuntu installation?

Again I apologize if there are logical flaws &| factual inaccuracies in my question. As I said I am totally new to Hadoop.

Thank you...

Comment: Short answer - yes. If your hardware is strong enough you can use multiple virtual machines. But it is definitely not the right place for this question.

Comment: @zero323 Why do you say it is not the right place for asking this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: why do you consider this off-topic? this question is in regards to "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: @HowardGuo 1. There wouldn't be a difference if question stated 'How can I emulate multiple machines on single Ubuntu host'. And this question has been already answered http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox 2. Most of the time there is quite big difference between Hadoop developer and Hadoop administrator. 3. I gave the answer in the comment, didn't I :)

Comment: @zero323 Are you sure the question is just all about emulating multiple machines? Aren't there any extra protocol stack built on top of clusters that differentiates it from a disjointed bunch of computers or multiple machines on a single computer? Isn't there special requirements that determine how communication takes place between nodes in a cluster.

Comment: @zero323  I am not saying I know answers to these questions. Just exploring, that's all..

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible using virtual machine.

if your machine is not capable it may be crash your system if you are working with multiple virtual machine.

for hadoop cluster setup you can create three virtual machine.
because hadoop default minimum file replication value is three. so the file replica is stored at three different VM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was exploring the possibility of running  watered down ubuntu kernel instances on the virtual machine. All I want is to be able to SSH into those ubuntu kernels & be able to run daemon threads (TaskTraker & DataNode) on those kernel instances. Please correct any factual inaccuracies in my questions. Thanks, Anup

Comment: This answer covers your question, and your question belongs in Server Fault, most likely, as it's more of a server admin question rather than a programming question (you're not alone; most of these hadoop-tagged questions belong there).